# Are cardinals always partial-well-ordered without AC?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

With AC, we have that cardinals are well-ordered. Without AC, we can have two sets which are incomparable, meaning that, at best, cardinals are only partially ordered.

But do we still have, without AC, that cardinals are at least partial-well-ordered, meaning there is no infinite descending chain of cardinals? Or can we have such infinite descending chains?

I had the thought that the existence of an infinite, Dedekind-finite set would suffice to prove that cardinals are not in general partial-well-ordered, since with those we have the property that if we remove any one element we get a strictly smaller cardinal. If we can show that this strictly smaller cardinal is always also Dedekind-finite, then we could remove another element to get an even smaller one, and so on. However, I am never quite sure how much this kind of reasoning really works in such bizarre models of ZF, so could use some clarity.

Comment: Your guess is correct. Remember that a set $X$ is Dedekind-finite iff it has no non-surjective self-injection. In particular, this means that if $x\in X$ then $X$ and $X\setminus\{x\}$ have different cardinalities, and so iterating this process if there is an infinite Dedekind-finite set there is a descending sequence of cardinalities.

Comment: There are probably other, better duplicates. In general, it is possible that every partially ordered set embeds into the cardinals. So in particular, there will be very long descending sequences of cardinals.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized these questions were the same thing. Does an infinite descending chain of cardinals mean that we have a necessarily *non-well-founded* model, though? For instance, with the infinite Dedekind-finite sets we have an infinite chain of non-isomorphic subsets, but I would have expected non-well-foundedness to be stronger, requiring an infinite chain of element membership.